# Update labels in JavaFX after selecting comboBox value

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to update labels in JavaFX upon selecting a value from the combobox.  The value in the comboBox represents an array object.  When I  load the page for the first time and select an option, it updates successfully.  However, when I select a different value in the comboBox the labels do not update.  Can anyone suggest why this might be?

```
package controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import app.TreatmentRoom;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DoctorAssessmentPageController implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
  @FXML
  private Label nhsNumberLabel;
  @FXML
  private Label titleLabel;
  @FXML
  private Label firstNameLabel;
  @FXML
  private Label lastNameLabel;

  ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Treatment Room 1", "Treatment Room 2",
      "Treatment Room 3", "Treatment Room 4", "Treatment Room 5");

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    comboBox.setItems(list);
  }

  @FXML
  private void buttonActionConfirmRoom(ActionEvent event) {
    switch (comboBox.getValue()) {
    case ("Treatment Room 1"):
      setPatientInfo(0);
      break;
    case ("Treatment Room 2"):
      setPatientInfo(1);
      break;
    case ("Treatment Room 3"):
      setPatientInfo(2);
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("treatment room not recognised");
    }

  }

  public void setPatientInfo(int i) {
    nhsNumberLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getNhsNumber());
    titleLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getTitle());
    firstNameLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getFirstName());
    lastNameLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getLastName());
  }



  @FXML
  private void btnLogout(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/views/FXMLLoginPage.FXML"));
    loader.load();
    Parent p = loader.getRoot();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(p));
    stage.show();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    // hides current page
    ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
  }

}
```

FXML for FXMLDoctorAssessmentPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000" stylesheets="@../styles/DoctorAssessmentPage1.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.DoctorAssessmentPageController">
  <children>
    <TabPane prefHeight="665.0" prefWidth="1385.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
      <tabs>
        <Tab text="Doctor Assessment">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="665.0" prefWidth="1385.0">
              <children>
                <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#517da6" height="90.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" styleClass="rectangle-pane" width="1385.0" />
                <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#72b2ee" height="53.0" layoutX="341.0" layoutY="494.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" styleClass="rectangle-pane2" width="193.0" />
                <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#72b2ee" height="426.0" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="121.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" styleClass="rectangle-pane2" width="237.0" />
                <Label fx:id="nhsNumberLabel" layoutX="59.0" layoutY="226.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="158.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" />
                <Label fx:id="titleLabel" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="282.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" text="Label" />
                <Label fx:id="allergiesLabel" layoutX="56.0" layoutY="442.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" text="allergiesLabel" />
                <Label layoutX="58.0" layoutY="403.0" styleClass="label-info" text="Allergies:" />
                <Label fx:id="bloodTypeLabel" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="365.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" text="bloodTypeLabel" />
                <Label layoutX="57.0" layoutY="329.0" styleClass="label-info" text="Blood type:" />
                <Label layoutX="58.0" layoutY="251.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="66.0" styleClass="label-info" text="Name:" />
                <Label layoutX="58.0" layoutY="201.0" styleClass="label-info" text="NHS Number:" />
                <Label fx:id="lastNameLabel" layoutX="181.0" layoutY="282.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" text="Label" />
                <Label fx:id="firstNameLabel" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="282.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" text="Label" />
                <Button fx:id="btnExtend5mins" layoutX="1038.0" layoutY="389.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnExtend5minsClick" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="161.0" styleClass="button-extension" text="5+ minutes" />
                <Button layoutX="1038.0" layoutY="124.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="161.0" text="Finalise Patient" />
                <TextArea layoutX="312.0" layoutY="122.0" prefHeight="321.0" prefWidth="270.0" promptText="Triage assessment" />
                <Label id="label-subTitle1" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="167.0" text="Patient" textFill="WHITE">
                  <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                  </font>
                </Label>
                <TextArea layoutX="621.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="321.0" prefWidth="394.0" promptText="Doctor assessment" />
                <Label fx:id="timeSpentLabel" layoutX="438.0" layoutY="508.0" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="66.0" styleClass="label-subTitle" text="Label" />
                <Label layoutX="348.0" layoutY="508.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0" styleClass="label-info" text="Time spent:" />
                <Button layoutX="1200.0" layoutY="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnLogout" text="Logout" />
                <Label fx:id="triageCategoryLabel" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="140.0" text="triageCategoryLabel" textFill="WHITE">
                  <font>
                    <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                  </font>
                </Label>
                <Label layoutX="348.0" layoutY="16.0" styleClass="label-title" text="Doctor Assessment &amp; Treatment Room" />
                        <Button layoutX="823.0" layoutY="504.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonActionConfirmRoom" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Confirm" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" layoutX="619.0" layoutY="505.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="190.0" promptText="Select Room" visibleRowCount="5" />
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Queue">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <children>
                <fx:include source="FXMLQueueTabPage.fxml" />
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab closable="false" text="Treatment Rooms">
          <content>
            <fx:include source="FXMLTreatmentRoomPage.fxml" />
          </content>
        </Tab>
      </tabs>
    </TabPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

thanks,
K

Comment: When is `buttonActionConfirmRoom` called?

Comment: This is a button on the FXML page.  When pressed it is supposed to get the value of comboBox and update the labels accordingly.

Comment: Show the relevant FXML

Comment: You don't have anything to trigger the method on selection in the combo box; the handler is only registered with a button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  How would I implement this?

Comment: Set the `onAction` for your `comboBox` to `"#buttonActionConfirmRoom"`. You have it set on a button, but not on the combo box, so the method is only triggered when you press the button, not when you select something in the combo box.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  The text fields update after selecting an initial value from the comboBox but when I select a different value from the comboBox they do not change.  Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Hard to tell from the code you have posted. My advice would be to do some simple debugging (see if the method is getting invoked at all; log the value of `comboBox.getValue()`, etc). If that doesn't lead you to the issue, create a [minimal, complete, executable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the issue and update your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you want the labels to be updated without clicking the button.

Here is a solution:

```
public class DoctorAssessmentPageController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
@FXML
private Label nhsNumberLabel;
@FXML
private Label titleLabel;
@FXML
private Label firstNameLabel;
@FXML
private Label lastNameLabel;

ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Treatment Room 1", "Treatment Room 2",
        "Treatment Room 3", "Treatment Room 4", "Treatment Room 5");

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     /* ******* Here is the Trick *********
    listens to the value property of the comboBox.
    calls the updateLabels function when the value changes. */
    comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            updateLabels(newValue);
        }
    });
    comboBox.setItems(list);
}

private void updateLabels(String newValue) {
    switch (newValue) {
        case ("Treatment Room 1"):
            setPatientInfo(0);
            break;
        case ("Treatment Room 2"):
            setPatientInfo(1);
            break;
        case ("Treatment Room 3"):
            setPatientInfo(2);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("treatment room not recognised");
    }

}

public void setPatientInfo(int i) {
    nhsNumberLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getNhsNumber());
    titleLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getTitle());
    firstNameLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getFirstName());
    lastNameLabel.setText(TreatmentRoom.treat[i].getPatient().getLastName());
}

@FXML
private void btnLogout(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/views/FXMLLoginPage.FXML"));
    loader.load();
    Parent p = loader.getRoot();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(p));
    stage.show();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    // hides current page
    ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
}
```

Regards,

Cyril